# using breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer at the breeze-object define

Tags: datetime, breeze, durandal

I work in durandal project and using breeze.
I retrive with the server (c#) object from sql into c# class, and it enter to a breeze-object which look exactly like the c# class.
when I define in the breeze object property with data-type "date-time", it doesn't convert the date-time of c# to date-time of breeze correctly.
I checked and finded the problem:
when it arrives to this point, it doesn't work well:

```js
function __isDate(o) {
    return __classof(o) === "date" && !isNaN(o.getTime());
}
```

in the watching-window I see that:  __classof(o)=> returns "string"!!!

so I looked in your site and see that there is option to use breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer.
but I dont want to use it in the javascript- logic, becouse after it enter the c# object into the breeze object, and doesn't convert it correctly, I lost the original date, and now this option can't help me.
so I want to use this option into the breeze-object.

here is my code:

```js
addEmployeePersonalDetailsType(store);
function addEmployeePersonalDetailsType(store) {
    store.addEntityType({
        shortName: "EmployeePersonalDetailsDTO",
        namespace: "eHarmonyServer.Entities",
        isComplexType: true,
        dataProperties: {
            BirthDay: { dataType: DataType.DateTime, isPartOfKey: false , validators: [Validator.date()] },
            EmmigrationDate: { dataType: DataType.DateTime, isPartOfKey: false },
            JobCode: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isPartOfKey: false },
            ChildCount: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isPartOfKey: false, isNullable: false },
            str_JobCode: { dataType: DataType.String, isPartOfKey: false },
            str_MaritalStatus: { dataType: DataType.String, isPartOfKey: false },
            validators: [Validator.double()]
        },
    });
    store.registerEntityTypeCtor("EmployeePersonalDetailsDTO", null, null);
}
```

I want to write:

```js
  EmmigrationDate: { dataType: DataType.parseDateFromServer, isPartOfKey: false },
```

but parseDateFromServer is function and it needs to acceps one parameter called "source". what should I send to it?
or- do you have another way to solve this problem?
thank you very match.

sample of class in file model.js:

```js
    addEmployeeMainDataType(store);
    function addEmployeeMainDataType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "EmployeeMainDTO",
            namespace: "eHarmonyServer.Entities",
            isComplexType: true,
            dataProperties: {
                FirstName: { dataType: DataType.String, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false, validators: [Validator.required()] },
                NickName: { dataType: DataType.String, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false },
                LastName: { dataType: DataType.String, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false, validators: [Validator.required()] },
                PassportNo: { dataType: DataType.String, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false },                    

                Date_start: { dataType: DataType.DateTime, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false, validators: [Validator.required()] },
                Date_end: {
                    dataType: DataType.DateTime, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false, validators: [Validator.date()
                        , validationHelper.complexTypeEndDateGreaterThanStartDateValidator({
                            startDateFieldName: "Date_start", resourceId: "1732",
                            entityName: 'employeeTblData',
                            entityNameSub: 'employeeMainData'
                        })]
                },
                HourPrice: { dataType: DataType.Double, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false },
                xActive: { dataType: DataType.Boolean, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: false },
                BalanceCalc: { dataType: DataType.Boolean, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: false }

            }

        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("EmployeeMainDTO", null, employeeMainDataInit);
    }
```

as you can see, I have more than one property from type "dateTime": Date_start, Date_end.
and I have a few classes else, which have properties of dateTime type, too.
so, the solution that suggest me to write initializer function for each field which is type date-  is not good for me.
I want that instead of write :

```js
    Date_start: { dataType: DataType.DateTime, isNullable: true, 
    Date_end: { dataType: DataType.DateTime, isNullable: true,
```

you will give me another type to write, that I will need to add only one converter function to code, and it will be generic function, not relative to specific field-name, such "birthday", "Data_end", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of durandal scripts changes the function "Date.parse" .
The new function cannot parse UTC date.

Here is my solution :
Add the following code to your model.js :

```
 breeze.DataType.parseDateFromServer = function (source)
    {
        var _localTimeRegex = /.\d{3}$/;
        if (typeof source === 'string') {
            // convert to UTC string if no time zone specifier.
            var isLocalTime = _localTimeRegex.test(source);
            source = isLocalTime ? source + 'Z' : source;
        }
        source = new Date(source);
        return source;
    }
```

This will override the function parseDateFromServer (in breeze.debug.js) to not use Date.parse .

Answer (score 2):

in your model.js (or however you call it where you define model on client side) you do following on initialization:

```
//...
metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('MyClass', null, myClassInitializer);
//...

function myClassInitializer(myClassInstance){
  myClassInstance.formattedDate = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
      return moment(myClassInstance.date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    },
    write: function (value) {
      myClassInstance.date(moment(value).toDate());
    }
  });
}
```

and then you just use `formattedDate` instead of `date`. Obviously, you need to translate into your variable names. Two-way binding from knockout ensures your `date` and `formattedDate` are always synced. Hopefully you get the point.

Comment: hello, thank you for your good answer. I tried using it, but it not did anything. can you explain better, what is "myClassInstance"? and how is "date()"? and, do I have to call function "myClassInitializer" as same as I call each function which creating dateType?

Comment: 'MyClass' is your object name, same as in your model. myClassInitializer is a function that is called automatically. myClassInstance is just a name you use as a local variable, it represents object on client which is of type MyClass. myClassInstance.date() represents reading value of MyClass.Date, just replace it with .birthday() or however your property is named. As written above, initializer is called automatically when breeze "materializes" an object as an instance of MyClass. Response is written generically since you didn't give server-side model which would be really readable.

Comment: Thanks for your advising and patience response. I have tow questions yet: 
1. what do you mean when you write : "Response is written generically since you didn't give server-side model which would be really readable."? 
2. it is problem to me that I have to write this code with specific names of class ('MyClass') and property ('birthDay'),

Comment: 2. it is problem to me that I have to write this code with specific names of class ('MyClass') and property ('birthDay'), becouse in my model I have some classes that I need them to use dates, and in each  of these classes I have some properties which their type should be date. so I need generic way to implement it. (it was the reason that I wanted to write DataType.parseDateFromServer).

Comment: Edit your question and add a sample class please. Generic = no real names, just dummy classes and properties, like "MyClass" and "date" property. Response was reffering to an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer assumes that you are using moment.js for formatting your dates.  Moment is an excellent library and you should definitely use it, but be wary of putting view formatting logic in your model definition or initialization.  The correct way to handle what you are trying to do is with a custom binding handler that handles your presentation logic to display the date the way that you want to.  To use this custom binding handler you do need to have moment.js referenced in your project.

Register a custom binding handler to handle date formatting in your view -

```
ko.bindingHandlers.Date = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var date = moment(value());
        var strDate = date.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        $(element).text(strDate);
    }
};
```

And then you can pass a string, a date, or anything else in and get a formatted date (just make sure you use some sort of date standard) -

```
<span data-bind="Date: myDate"></span>
```

**Keep in mind**

This is to take in a date without having to change what the server is returning.  If you can do that and return a UTC date or some other standard date format instead of a string this makes it even easier for you.

Comment: I don't think that would help out with data-binding to an `<input type="date" ... />` problem. That was main reason why I used previous solution which ended up being pretty bad in a long run (too much code for initialization every date in different classes).

Comment: Where do you see anything related to editing a date in an input box in the question?

Comment: I don't, but date might be changed at some point and to cover that, you might want something different :)